# Cannot do operation with result from Android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am taking value from webview using JavascriptInterface. I receive the value alright.
But when i make an "equal to" check to the value, it does not work?
This is my java code.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void check(String p) {
    if(p == "apple"){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

And this is the javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var p = "apple";
function check(p){
Android.check(p);
}
check(p);
</script>
```

Comment: Did my answer provide a solution? If so please mark it as correct to close the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
if(p == "apple"){
```

to this

```
if(p.equals("apple"){
```

More info thanks to Rafał Zajfert [Here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/36424446/4252751)

Your entire code would look like this:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void check(String p) {
    if(p.equals("apple")){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what to do that?

Comment: @paulcab Check my edit, simply change what's inside your if statment

Answer (score 0):

compare your strings using .equals() method:

```
if(p.equals("apple")){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```